# Show "battery so far" chart instead of the "projected battery life" chart in Marshmallow

Tags: battery-life, 6.0-marshmallow

After the update to Marshmallow, I notice the battery level chart is different that I had it with K. In KitKat, the chart was "last charge until now" long, but in Marshmallow it is "last charge until projected life" long.

The projected life is not really as useful as they might have anticipated it to be, its accuracy is questionable, and it only skews the scale of the chart. And it usually is not a small wasted space - on the contrary, usually it is much wider than the rest (currently 3/4 of the entire chart width).

Is it possible to revert to a KitKat style battery life chart?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's different that much, other than some small "wasted" space on the right if you think the projected life is not useful. But AFAIK, it's impossible to change that natively.

Comment: @AndrewT. - the part I really want to get rid of is the projected life. It is not really as useful as they might have anticipated it to be, its accuracy is BS, and it only skews the scale of the chart. And it usually is not a small wasted space - on the contrary, usually it is much wider than the rest.

Comment: Currently the projected part takes over 3/4 of the entire chart width.

Comment: I see, fair enough. Yeah, it's scaled to the last charge. Sorry I was biased about "small space" because I haven't charged until full for 1 day (the projected life is only 10% of the width), but AFAIK, it's impossible to remove that functionality. Perhaps someone has better solution.